# How to simplify ( ~A * B) + C * (~B + A)

Tags: boolean, simplification

I have simplified a Boolean function up to a point but I got stuck on the last step, I can't see which rule (if any) I should apply to get to the simplified expression.

I want to simplify the following Boolean function:

( ~A * B) + C * (~B + A)

I know the simplified form is (B * ~A + C), but I can't identify which rules should I use, although I can see that ( ~A * B) and (~B + A) cancel each other, but I'm not sure if there is a rule for this or is this based on pure observation.

The rules I have tried to use are detailed here http://electronics-course.com/boolean-algebra

Anybody could give me a hand?

Thanks!

Comment: That's not really a programming question (even though programming uses lots of logic), but more of a math question I'd say. And as such it would be better on [the mathematics stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Thanks!. I saw some similar questions being answered on stack before, but as you said is not a "programming" question per se, I'll try on Math exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                   ( ~A * B) + C * (~B + A)
~C * ( ~A * B) + C*( ~A * B) + C * (~B + A)    X = X*Y + X*~Y
~C * ( ~A * B) + C*( ~A * B) + C * ~(B * ~A)   De Morgan
~C * ( ~A * B) + C                             X*Y + X*~Y = X 
     ( ~A * B) + C                             Absorption
```

Not sure if `X = X*Y + X*~Y` has a name, you can derive it from:

```
x 
X * 1            Idempotence
X * (Y + ~Y)     Complement
X * Y + X * ~Y   Distributive Law
```

**Edit:** I found a simpler way:

```
                   ( ~A * B) + C * (~B + A) 
                   ( ~A * B) + C * ~(B * ~A)   De Morgan
                   ( ~A * B) + C * ~(~A * B)   Commutative Law
                   ( ~A * B) + C               Absorption
```

Comment: Many many thanks! I tried C * ~(B * ~A) before but since I didn't use X = X*Y + X*~Y I was going nowhere!